# Get data from combobox to database

Tags: java, sql, combobox

I'm trying to get category name from combobox and then insert it to my database

This is my code, but I don't know how to write the code to make this work. Any ideas ?

The below code is my add button (trying to make work String value, String query). However, the code is really wrong I think.

```
String value=jComboBox_Category2.getSelectedItem().toString();
String qquery="INSERT INTO   Products ( Cat_products) VALUES ('"+Cat_products.getText()+" ') ";
String query="INSERT INTO Products(Pro_Id ,Pro_Name,Pro_Price,Pro_Quantity,Pro_Supplier_id,Pro_Tax)VALUES ('"+Pro_Id.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Name.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Price.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Quantity.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Supplier_id.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Tax.getText()+" ') ";
executeSQLQuery(query,"Inserted");
```

Here is the code that my other elements get the data. So where do I have to write the code? And how should it be like?

```
public ArrayList<Update_del_insert_products> getproList() {
    ArrayList<Update_del_insert_products> proList =new ArrayList<Update_del_insert_products> ();
    Connection connection =getConnection();
    String query ="SELECT * FROM Products";
    Statement stt;
    ResultSet rss;
    try{
        stt = connection.createStatement();
        rss = stt.executeQuery(query);
        Update_del_insert_products  update_del_insert_products ;
        while(rss.next()) {
            update_del_insert_products = new Update_del_insert_products (rss.getString("Pro_Id"),rss.getString("Pro_Name"),rss.getString("Pro_Price"),rss.getString("Pro_Quantity"),rss.getString("Pro_Supplier_id"),rss.getString("Pro_Tax"));
            proList.add(update_del_insert_products);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return proList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String qquery="INSERT INTO  Products (Cat_products) VALUES (Cat_products.getText()");
Connection connection = (see below)
Statment stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(qquery)
```

But you can concatenate insert statements if you use the same table

In order to retrieve data from database, first of all have to set the connection properly

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=YourDatabseName;integratedSecurity=true;")//without authentication
```

You should not use * in sql statement.
Make setter and getter methods in Update_del_insert_product class (Auto-generated methods) and use them.

```
while(rss.next()){
    update_del_insert_products product = new Update_del_insert_products();
    int i = 1
    product.setPro_ID(rss.getString(Pro_ID, i++));
    product.setPro_Name(rss.getString(Pro_Name, i++));
    ...

    prolist.add(product);
}
```